# Laravel 4 - Extend application controller from a package

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, laravel-4

**Background**

I know what I'm trying to do sounds a bit wrong but I do have my reasons.
Basically I have a central core app that's a default laravel app with a few tweaks and boilerplate code, I have then developed a series of packages that can be used to extend the app through composer. These packages are not meant to function without the core framework so a dependency upon it is fully expected.

**What I want to do**

What I would like to do is have a BaseController in my core app and have the various controllers in my package extend this BaseController to provide universal functionality throughout the various module packages.

I was expecting to be able to place the base controller in `app/controllers/BaseController.php`
and then extend it from my package using:

```
class PackageController extends \BaseController{}
```

Unfortunately when I do this it still looks within the package (currently workbenched) for the controller and I get the error:

> include(/var/www/l4core.dev/workbench/myvendor/mypackage/src/controllers/BaseController.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here. I am looking for a solution which allows me to easily move my packages between vendor dir and workbench for development. Any help greatly appreciated

**Update**

The previously mentioned error message appears to have been due to an include in my packages `/vendor/composer/classloader.php` - I have now deleted the vendor directory and done a fresh composer install. This has not solved the problem but it has at least shifted it as I now get the following error message:

> Class 'BaseController' not found

*My Packages composer.json*

```
{
    "name": "modules/sesame",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "any",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/support": "4.0.x",
        "zizaco/confide": "dev-master",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master",
        "conarwelsh/mustache-l4": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "src/controllers",
            "src/models",
            "src/migrations",
            "src/seeds"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
            "Modules\\Sesame": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: It is really strange that you have an "include" error, usually it is a "Class not found". Can you give us a snippet of your package composer.json file?

Comment: @FR6 Thanks for giving it some attention - I have added the composer.json for the package.

Comment: You say, you put `BaseController` in `app` directory => `app/BaseController.php`. I am not sure autoloading works just from `app` directory, try to place controller into `app/controllers` or any other folder included in autoloading.

Comment: Sorry, no it's not, that was a typo, the controller is in `app/controllers`

Comment: I have updated my question as I now have a standard class not found message after a fresh composer install

Comment: Be sure to execute `php artisan dump-autoload` and verify that your class `BaseController` is in `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.

Comment: I had tried that and got an error about the clear-complied pre-update event failing because the class was missing. I'll delete vendor folder in the main app, re-install and post back

Comment: @FR6 +all Thanks for your help, its working now. The solution of deleting the vendor directory and running composer install seems a little long-winded but it did the job. I dont understand why dump-autoload didnt work though. Does anyone want to present this as an answer so that I can accept (if you have any ideas why dump-autoload didnt work that would be a welcome inclusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to execute:

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

And verify that your class `BaseController` is in `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.

OR like the OP stated, removing the `vendor` directory and running `composer install` again could sometimes solve the problem.